# Codeigniter pagination doesn't show page relevant data, but the whole data set

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-3

Here is my controller :

```
function index()
{
    $data['title']="Post";
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'Post/index';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->post_model->get_total_count();
    $config['per_page'] = 1;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 1;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['posts'] = $this->post_model->get_single_post($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(1));

    $this->load->view('frontend/layouts/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('frontend/view_post',$data);
    $this->load->view('frontend/layouts/footer');
}
```

**Model**

```
function get_single_post(){
$query= $this->db->select('*')
    ->from('tbl_post,tbl_users')
    ->where('tbl_post.post_created=tbl_users.user_id')
    ->where('tbl_post.post_status',1)
    ->order_by('tbl_post.post_id','asc')
    ->get();
    $data = $query->result_array();
    return $data;
    }



function get_total_count(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_post');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->num_rows();
    }
```

The relevant page data doesn't show. It shows all of the data in one page!

Comment: what you mean  by ***per page data couldn't show***. Cz it's there  in your code `$config['per_page'] = 1;`

Comment: it shows all of database data. but i want to show per page 1 data but it couldn't

Comment: missing `$data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();` ??

Comment: i show it view page like this: `<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();?>`

Answer (score 1):

> **`$config['uri_segment'] = 1` are you sure on this ??** [Check this CI example](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html#example)

As you mentioned `$config['base_url'] = base_url().'Post/index';` in question `$config['uri_segment'] = 1` should be `$config['uri_segment'] = 2`

---

As well doo this too

**In Controller**

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 1;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
$data['posts'] = $this->post_model->get_single_post($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(1));
```

**In View**

```
echo $links;
```

---

**Edit 01**

In Model add this

```
function get_single_post($page,$limit) # Changed
{
    $query= $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('tbl_post,tbl_users')
        ->where('tbl_post.post_created=tbl_users.user_id')
        ->where('tbl_post.post_status',1)
        ->limit($page,$limit) # Changed
        ->order_by('tbl_post.post_id','asc')
        ->get();
    $data = $query->result_array();
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: how much i input in uri segment. my base url is `base_url().'Post/index'` . i add 1 but all pages are show same data

Comment: i add uri segment = 2 ; but my page show all data again. i just show only per page number : like 2 data.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of problem.

1. `$config['uri_segment']` cannot be 1. It should be 3
   So fix it to

   `$config['uri_segment']`=3;

segment 1 means controller name.
2 means function name.
3 means page number.
if you use 1 it will replace the controller name with page number.

2. You passing parameter to your model function but your model not receiving the parameters.So your function should be like this

   `function get_single_post($limit,$page_no){`
3. Your model returning all records not the current page records. So add limit

   `->limit($page_no,$limit)//remember page_no should be 0 for 1,1 for 2.`

Comment: yes it solved . i mistake on uri segment, and in model : limit option .. thanks all